# from json urdu font not showing in android listview

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, font-face, urdu

I want to show Urdu font from json service and I' m using it in English version it shows correctly. But when I want to show Urdu language from json to android
it does not show urdu language proper.. how to fix that issue

Comment: Are you using UTF-8 or Urdu code page?

Comment: yes i am using using ut8 and json is showing urdu text properly

Comment: why android is not showing urdu text from json service ?

Comment: my json is also not showing urdu language it shows ???

Comment: I assume json is generated on the server side and that it is generated as UTF-8. Please, confirm.